# Sorting duplicate entries in a List

Tags: java, android

I am trying to sort from a list.

ex:

Album artist X (year), 
Album artist Y (2000), 
Album artist Y (1971), 
Album artist Y (1980), 
Album artist Z (year)

I would like to sort album artist Y by year without changing its position between X and Z

Album artist X (year), 
Album artist Y (1971), 
Album artist Y (1980), 
Album artist Y (2000), 
Album artist Z (year)

My current code:

```
public class AlbumListLoader extends BaseLoader<List<? extends Item>> implements MPDConfig {

private Artist mArtist = null;
private List<? extends Item> mItems = null;

public AlbumListLoader(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public AlbumListLoader(Context context, Artist artist) {
    super(context);
    mArtist = artist;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<? extends Item> loadInBackground() {

    final String tri = mSettings.getString("tri", "az");

    try {

        mItems = MPDApplication.getInstance().oMPDAsyncHelper.oMPD.getAlbums(mArtist);

       if (tri.equals("year")) {
           Collections.sort((List<? extends Album>) mItems, Album.SORT_BY_YEAR_DSC);
       } else if (tri.equals("artist")) {

           if (mArtist == null) {
               Collections.sort((List<? extends Album>) mItems, Album.SORT_BY_ARTIST);

           // Here, I want to sort Album + by date

           }
       }

    } catch (final IOException | MPDException ignore) {
        Log.w("AlbumListLoader", "Failed to update.");
    }

    return mItems;
}
```

My Album sort:

```
public static final Comparator<AbstractAlbum> SORT_BY_ARTIST = new Comparator<AbstractAlbum>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(final AbstractAlbum lhn, final AbstractAlbum rhn) {

        final String leftArtist = lhn.mArtist;
        final String rightArtist = rhn.mArtist;

        return leftArtist.compareToIgnoreCase(rightArtist);
    }
};
```

I do not see how to do it, an idea ?

**EDIT: Resolved**

```
if (leftArtist.equalsIgnoreCase(rightArtist)) {

            int compare = 0;
            final int leftYear = formattedYear(lhn.mYear);
            final int rightYear = formattedYear(rhn.mYear);

            if (leftYear < rightYear) {
                compare = -1;
            } else if (leftYear > rightYear) {
                compare = 1;
            }

            if (compare == 0) {
                compare = lhn.compareTo(rhn);
            }

            return compare;

        } else {

            return leftArtist.compareToIgnoreCase(rightArtist);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove your duplicate entry from album then you can use java `Set` and `HashSet` as follows

```
Set<List<? extends Album> testList = new HashSet<List<? extends Album>(mItems);
```

this will remove duplicate entry from your `mItems` list. now you can add duplicate removed list 'testList' in your `ArrayList` as follows

```
yourList.addAll(testList);
```

Now you can filter list according to your need.
I hope its work for you.